# rails devise - multiple register url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

At first I used devise register for one type of user.
 Works perfectly well, but now I add 2 specifics routes `register/users` for lambda users and `register/pro` for professional.

Theses two routes uses the same model users, with just changing the form view.

But when I submit the form, in case of failure I am redirect to `/users/` and nothing else appends.

To do that, I have done this :

```
get '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register # original version
# and added :
get '/register/users', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register_users
get '/register/professional', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register_pro
```

But, like I said, nothing appends but redirect to `/users/` if the form is badly filled.

So I also tried to add this :

```
post '/register/users' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :register
post '/register/professional' =>   'devise/registrations#create', :as => :register
```

But same result.

I'm doing something wrong, anybody as an idea?

Thanks !

EDIT :

For now, the problem is that in case of badly fill the formulaire,this redirect to `./users`and not to `register/users`. But in case of succeded, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You need override `after_sign_up_path_for` in a Controller(usually ApplicationController)

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if resource.type == :pro # please modify this line
    some_your_path
  else
    super # this will be /users/
  end
end
```

I assume you have `User` model. Then this `resource` is user object. And I assume you have some attribute in User model to find pro/non-pro. Please use that attribute for 'if' statement and write paths.

If you use Confirmable you need to override `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` instead of `after_sign_up_path_for`.

Comment: Hum I tried but nothing change, It don't even go in that method. I don't thinks this is going to work. I think the post method isn't call... my model is the same and don't make difference between pro and non-pro, except an attribute set to true/false. But I want to use 2 different url. Thoses two roots use the same html file, the devise html for `registration/new`, and show differents form if url contains "users" or "professional". But when I confirm the form, nothing appends but redirect to `/users/` (but not even `/register/users/`). I think it's a problem of routes